# Scroll down pages with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

this is the problem:

I am using selenium to download all the successful projects from this webpage ("https://www.rockethub.com/projects"). The url does not change if a click on any button.
I'm interested in successful project, thus I click on the button status and then I click on successful.

Once on this page I need to scroll down repedetly to make other urls appear.
Here is the problem. So far I have been not able to scroll down the page

This is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver



url="https://www.rockethub.com/projects"

link=[]

wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get(url)

next_button = wd.find_element_by_link_text('Status')
next_button.click()

next_but = wd.find_element_by_link_text('Successful')
next_but.click()

wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Giangi

Comment: Which is your operating system? what version of python are you using.?

Comment: I use Windows; version of Python is 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the content is updated dynamically, you need to wait for a change of the content before executing the next step:

```py
class element_is_not(object):
    """ An expectation for checking that the element returned by
    the locator is not equal to a given element.
    """

    def __init__(self, locator, element):
        self.locator = locator
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, driver):
        new_element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
        return new_element if  self.element != new_element else None


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.rockethub.com/projects")

# get the last box
by_last_box = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.project-box:last-of-type')
last_box = wait.until(element_is_not(by_last_box, None))

# click on menu Status > Successful
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Status').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Successful').click()

# wait for a new box to be added
last_box = wait.until(element_is_not(by_last_box, last_box))

# scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

# wait for a new box to be added
last_box = wait.until(element_is_not(by_last_box, last_box))
```

Comment: ThankYou! This helped a lot. Code works well and explanation was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` in loop, since each time the script is executed only certain number of data is rerieved, so you have to execute it in a loop.

If you are just looking to retrieve all the successful projects at once and not interested in simulating the scrolling down to the page, then look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821934/1437877), it may help.